# Is there any information known about the weapons used by Tempestarii?

Tags: warframe

In the latest Warframe update - [Call of the Tempestarii](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Update_30) - Tenno can embark on a quest of the same name and investigate strange events taking place in the Corpus Proxima. However, considering the update released as little as 2 days ago at the time of writing, many Tenno might have not gotten the chance to play through the quest yet. If my use of spoilers isn't in place, I apologize in advance.

> During the [Call of the Tempestarii quest](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Call_of_the_Tempestarii), players encounter the "ghost ship" Tempestarii on multiple occasions. In the [last part of the quest](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Call_of_the_Tempestarii#Signal_the_Tempestarii), both at the start when Cephalon Cy is signaling Tempestarii, and in the last stage when players get to pilot the ship while Tempestarii readies her armaments, player gets to first evade, then use a **new Railjack turret that fires slow-moving, homing, pressumably void-based energy projectiles.** Is there any information known about this weapon? I was unable to find any mention on the [armaments wiki page](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Railjack/Armaments#Turrets) and all searches containing the update name + "weapon" return only the new Sevagoth's hand cannon - Epitaph. As a rarely seen avid Railjack player (really, most of my friends frankly don't enjoy it), I'd be very interested in getting my hands on the weapon. I am curious if any details on it have been revealed by Digital Extremes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information provided on the ship can be found under [Sevegoth](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Sevagoth/Main#Lore) and the [quest page](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Call_of_the_Tempestarii) itself. The weapons used by the Tempestarii are currently exclusive to it and not usable on Tenno Railjacks. However, they function similar to [Grineer](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Gokstad_Crewship) and [Corpus](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Crewship) crewship weapons which also fire homing missiles.